# Register CallBackHandler IOS application,SUP,Xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode4.2, sup

we are following the steps mentioned in the infocentersybase. we need to register a cal back to retrive the information.ie, the following step

**To configure an application to synchronize and retrieve MBO data you must start the client
engine, configure the physical device settings, listen for messages from the server, and
subscribe to a package.

1. Register a callback.

Development Task Flows
Developer Guide: iOS Native Applications 13
The client framework uses a callback mechanism to notify the application when messages
arrive from the server. Some examples of events that are sent include login success or
failure, subscription success or failure, or a change to a MBO.
Register the callback object by executing:

> `MyCallbackHandler* theCallbackHandler = [MyCallbackHandler new];
>   [SampleApp_SampleAppDB registerCallbackHandler:theCallbackhandler];`

We have `SUPCallBackHandler.h` file and `SUPDefaultCallBackHandler.h` in the public directory. so Where should we write the corresponding .m files. Please help us. if question is not clear then jus read that above mentioned step and please explain what does that mean. please help us.